# Get that particular ID records and express higher fields obtained as string in sqlite table

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have a table called temporal which has fields called number, phone number, date, time, sms, all type being text, except that the number is integer field. On the other hand I have an integer variable called IndexId and what I want is to select the fields phone, date, time and sms from the temporary table whose number is greater than the value of IndexId. Once done drain fields phone, date, time and sms on variables of type String. How I would do?. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What about selecting your desired columns and adding a preferred WHERE clause?

```
SELECT phone, date, time, sms
  FROM temporal
 WHERE number > IndexId;  -- if IndexId is a column in the same table
```

Additional recommendations: you should rename your columns since `number`, `data` and `time` could be some keywords.

How about:

```
number => tmp_number
data => tmp_date
time => tmp_time
```

Comment: I did the test and when the expression: WHERE number> IndexId the application is not closed but the place does not work: abruptly closed.

Comment: IndexId in a variable of type integer. It is a column of any table.

Comment: The correct expression is: Cursor this.baseDatos.rawQuery cur1 = ("SELECT number, phone number, date, time, time FROM sms where number> '" + IndexId + "'", null);
So fix the problem.

Comment: Is this a question? Then please ask properly! `IndexId` can be either a variable OR a column. I don't know your whole code, but this statement of your last comment is not a valid Java statement since `Cursor` is probably a class, `this.baseDatos.rawQuery` is a member of a class and `cur1` is a variable. So this is not a variable declaration statement! Show us some more code and the correct table structure you have, if you need an correct answer!